# OV5642 does not work issue

Tags: camera, image-sensor

I've got OV5642 camera module initialize issue.

I put 3.3V and 24Mhz XCLK into the camera. I've double checked it.
But it does not make a initial work.

there is no PCLK output

there is no HREF, VSYNC outputs

there is no D[9:0] output

Can you help me please the initialize that camera?
Should I have to do something else to get those signal at the power up?

[image]

## update

[image]

Comment: What does the datasheet say? Often there is a RESET and/or PWDN line that needs to be pulled up or down and there may also be some initialization sequence necessary before it will work. The datasheet is essential reading.

Comment: @RogerRowland Thanks for a opinion. the data sheet say that "PWDN active high, should be connected to ground outside of module if unused" so I did. but it's not working. is this need once up and down?

Comment: Do you also have RESET exposed? That's active-low with an internal pullup but might be worth briefly grounding after power up, then connect to Vdd to keep it high. Keep PWDN grounded at all times.

Comment: @RogerRowland I've updated with pin map. there is no RESET. and PWDN is always grounded.

Comment: How about the TWI pins? Are they pulled up? Try a bus scan and see if the module responds. Can you post the pin labels behind the camera? You're sure your camera is a 5642?

Comment: @TisteAndii, That is not responding about TWI. yes it's 5642

Comment: The OV56xx sensors, or any omivision cameras, or any camera in general, needs to have  few hundred i2c registers configured, and a few to get it start capturing images.

Answer (score 1):

If all connections are correct, then I support @RogerRowland comment - the sensor needs to be initialized/configured before it will work. I used one of the Omnivision sensors without configuration (did not know there should be one) and I had the signals all working, however, the pixel data was not correct. In your case, it may be possible that the configuration is necessary before getting any output signals.

The SCL and SDATA pins are used to configure the sensor. It is a pretty much I2C interface. There should be a list of registers that must be configured for proper functionality.

EDIT:

If you are sure that your sensor can show signs of life without configuration, then the sensor/board seems to be dysfunctional. I would still try to do some reads/writes to the registers, or at least, reconfigure the clock register - it looks like the chip can take a wide range of clock frequencies (6-54MHZ). Try contacting the vendor.

Comment: Naz, I have been  experienced with OV7670, As I know basically Omnivision camera is working without initial configuration( even that output image sucks, but it can be found the camera ouput).

Comment: I just started working with OV5640, and it does have registers that are responsible for enabling output pads (and they are set to disable by default). Therefore, those registers should be configured before any output. I would expect the same behaviour in OV5642. Check the datasheet.